# Dealing with Bootstrap's column's free spaces

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a big problem with `Bootstrap`'s grid system. My problem is free space in result of being only 12 sections in a row:

[image]

As you can see, this two column's have only 1 point difference with each other but because of big effort of each point in gird system, they have a free space between them.

So if we have a BIG screen, that free space will be much bigger. What I want is something like that this: each column just wrap it's content and remove unnecessary space! Since I use `Bootstrap`'s grid system in my whole project, I have to use it but I want a feature like `wrap-content`.

Event if a row can be more than 12 section's, we could create more accurate parts.

In this situation that described in the picture, if I resize page, cols could overlap on each other too. I just they stay beside each other with a little space.

Comment: you can make 12 columns inside one row but  inside that .col-lg-2 you can create again 12 columns..

Comment: Why not set `col-lg-2` in both if you have same content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra space is exactly because Bootstrap set the width to the `col-*` in **%**.

e.g

```
.col-xs-3 {
    width: 25%;
}
.col-xs-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
}
```

[Check this out for more information](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

By doing this you will achieve what you want:

```
.wrap-content{
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid; /*only to show the boundaries of the elements*/
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 wrap-content">
        <button class="my-btn">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 wrap-content">
        <button class="my-btn">button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/rw0w8q4s/1/)

But I really recommend you to use a different markup, do not change the grid system of bootstrap eventually this can create inconsistencies.

I'm using `col-xs` just to make viable the jsfiddle example, change it to your desired `col-`.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying

```
float:right
```

for col-lg-2 and

```
float:left
```

for col-lg-3

Comment: with this, i can't align this two button with other elements in page. left button always will be inner than it's parent.